# How to display the names of an ambassador's godchildren in a list?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a sponsorship system and I would like to display the names of the godchildren in a list.

I have a list of'ambassadors' whose ambassadors will have godchildren who will have other godchildren. At the moment I manage to display the number of godchildren for each ambassador, but I have trouble creating the script to display the name. Could you help me? Thank you.

```
public function adminAmbassadorsAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var UserManager $userManager * */
        $ambassadors = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); # Getting the entity manager for future request.

        /** @var UserRepository $repository * */
        $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User');

        // Recup all ambassadors
        $ambassadors = $repository->findByRole("ROLE_AMBASSADOR");

        $proprietesAmbassadeur = array();

        // Iterate ambassadors
        foreach ($ambassadors as $ambassador) {

            // Recup all fileuls
            // $ambassador = $this->getFullName();  // recup name parrain

            $filleuls = $repository->findBy(array('parrain' => $ambassador->getId()));  

            foreach ($filleuls as $filleul) {
                ($filleul->getFullName());

            }

            $proprietesAmbassadeur[$ambassador->getId()] = count($filleuls);
        }

        // render the view
        return $this->render('Admin/listing_sponsor.html.twig', [
            'os_ambassadors' => $ambassadors,
            'os_proprietes' => $proprietesAmbassadeur,
        ] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the god childs to the view.

I've rewritten your code so it passes the total of god childs and all their names.

```
public function adminAmbassadorsAction(Request $request)
{
    /** @var UserManager $userManager * */
    $ambassadors = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); # Getting the entity manager for future request.

    /** @var UserRepository $repository * */
    $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User');

    // Recup all ambassadors
    $ambassadors = $repository->findByRole("ROLE_AMBASSADOR");

    $proprietesAmbassadeur = array();

    // Iterate ambassadors
    foreach ($ambassadors as $ambassador) {

        // Recup all fileuls
        // $ambassador = $this->getFullName();  // recup name parrain

        $filleuls = $repository->findBy(array('parrain' => $ambassador->getId()));

        $proprietesAmbassadeur[$ambassador->getId()] = array('total' => count($filleuls), 'filleulFullNames' => array());
        foreach ($filleuls as $filleul) {
            $proprietesAmbassadeur[$ambassador->getId()]['filleulFullNames'][] = $filleul->getFullName();
        }


    }

    // render the view
    return $this->render('Admin/listing_sponsor.html.twig', [
        'os_ambassadors' => $ambassadors,
        'os_proprietes' => $proprietesAmbassadeur,
    ] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I have an error that looks like this: 
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

and the line of code assigned is: $proprietesAmbassador[$ambassador->getId()]['filleulFullNames'][] = $filleul->getFullName();

Comment: @FranciscoBeronPerez I editted my code. I forgot to declare 'filleulFullNames' as an array before using it as an array.

Comment: No problem. If my answer fixed it for you, could you accept it as the answer?